# How do I add a border to a div inside a grid-container without messing up the structure?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am using grids to create an interface. Inside the container, I want to have a wrapper (div) with a border around it. But when I place the grid-items inside the wrapper the structure is destroyed. How do I do to maintain intended structure inside the wrapper?

Without the wrapper, with the desired structure (the button at the bottom is not positioned correctly yet):

[image: Without the wrapper]

This is how it looks with the wrapper, unfortunately:

[image: With Wrapper]

Here you can see the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k5ozvuef/)!

**HTML**

```
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="col3r7">
      <label class="id">gggg</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col4r7">
      <label class="monkey">hhhhhhhh hhh hh</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col3r9">
      <label class="ape">iiiiiiL</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col3r11">
      <label class="bob">jjjjjj/kkkk</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col3r13">
      <label class="pepsi">lllll</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col3r15">
      <label class="cocacola">lllll</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col3r17">
      <label class="benice">nnnnns</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col3r19">
      <label class="tome">ooo pppp qqqqq]</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col3r21">
      <label class="many">rrrr rr rrrr</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col3r23">
      <label class="labels">ssss</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col4r25">
      <button class="done">ttttt</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 7;
  grid-row-start: 6;
  grid-row-end: 25;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.grid-container {
  display: inline-grid;
  height: 833vh;
  width: 100vw;
  grid-template-columns: 15.62vw 2.01vw 21.87vw 12.08vw 19.37vw 8.95vw 4.58% auto;
  grid-template-rows: 7.32vh 3.51vh 2.53vh 1.56vh 0.39vh 1.37vh 2.34vh 1.66vh 1.56vh 0.88vh 1.56vh 1.76vh 1.56vh 0.88vh 1.85vh 1.76vh 1.56vh 0.88vh 1.56vh 1.76vh 1.56vh 0.88vh 1.85vh 2.54vh 2.24vh 1.66vh;
  grid-template-areas: "sidebar head head head head head thinbar sidebar" "sidebar head head head head head thinbar sidebar" "sidebar main main main main main thinbar sidebar";
}

.col1r1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.col2r1 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 8;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}

.col6r2 {
  grid-column-start: 6;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}

.col3r4 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-row-start: 4;
}

.col4r4 {
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-row-start: 4;
}

.col3r7 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-row-start: 7;
}

.col4r7 {
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-row-start: 7;
}

.col3r9 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-row-start: 9;
}

.col3r11 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-row-start: 11;
}

.col3r13 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-row-start: 13;
}

.col3r15 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-row-start: 15;
}

.col3r17 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-row-start: 17;
}

.col3r19 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-row-start: 19;
}

.col3r21 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-row-start: 21;
}

.col3r23 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-row-start: 23;
}

.col4r25 {
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-row-start: 25;
}

.col3r26 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-row-start: 26;
}

.done {
  height: 2.24vh;
  width: 3.33vw;
}
```

Comment: Can we please have a **reduced** demo...try removing everything not related to the issue.

Comment: Also, as I'm sure you are aware, grid-cells *are not elements* so you can't put borders around them.

Comment: I have cleaned up the code... Ok, but how do you do to add a border like this if you are creating a webpage in which Grid-CSS is used? Since people are doing it, there must be a workaround of some sort!

Comment: It's not clear to me what the final result should look like.

Comment: The final result should have the same structure as the first image, but with a border that begins between the top labels and ends below the last button. The difference between how it is now and how it should be, is that when I use the wrapper all content is placed in the first column when it should be distributed in two columns.

Comment: You can't apply the grid-properties of the "container" to the internal components of the one of the container's children (the wrapper)....yet. You'd need some other layout mechanism or decide which borders will go around which elements to make what **appears** to be a continuous "wrapper".